# NQueens puzzle, queens not placing?

Tags: java, recursion

I'm writing a recursive program for the NQueens problem, with a specified board size. My problem is, the queens are not being placed on the board and I'm not sure why. I've tried tracing out the program but I'm still not seeing my issue. Any suggestions?

```
public class Main {


public static boolean[][] board;

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter size of board");
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    board = new boolean[n][n];

    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++) {

            board[i][j] = false;
        }
    }

    NQueens(0);
    printBoard();
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {

            if (board[i][j] == true) {

                System.out.println((i + 1) + " " + (j + 1));

            }
        }
    }
}

static boolean NQueens(int col) {
    if (col >= board.length)
        return true;

    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        if (checkNotBlocked(col, i)) {
            board[col][i] = true;
            if (NQueens(col + 1))
                return true;

            board[col][i] = false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

static boolean checkNotBlocked(int col, int row) {

    for (int i = 0; i < col; i++) {
        if (board[i][row] == true)
            return false;
    }

    for (int i = col; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = row; j >= 0; j--) {
            if (board[i][j] == true)
                return false;
        }
    }
    for (int i = col; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = row; j < board.length; j++) {

            if (board[i][j] == true)
                return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}


static void printBoard() {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {
            if (board[i][j] == true) {
                System.out.print("Q\t");
            } else {
                System.out.print("_\t");
            }
        }
            System.out.println("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your best bet: Step through the program with a debugger to see what it's doing as it runs.

Comment: this doesn't seem to answer true

Answer (score 0):

Your checks on the diagonals are incorrect.  You used nested loops, which means that you're checking an entire rectangle, rather than just the diagonals of the containing square.  If there is a queen on *any* other row within the bounding box, you will refuse to place the next queen.  Since this will happen after the first queen is placed, you'll never get a second queen onto the board.

Note the difference in logic from what you have:

```
for (int i = col; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (int j = row; j >= 0; j--) {
        if (board[i][j] == true)
            return false;
    }
}
```

... which iterates through all ordered pairs from [col][row] down to [0][0] ... versus checking the diagonal only:

```
for (int i = col, j = row;   // My apologies if this isn't legal Java;
     i >= 0 & j >= 0;        //   I'm out of practice.
     i--, j--) {             // i and j must decrement *together*.

    if (board[i][j])
            return false;
    }
}
```

Do likewise for the opposite diagonal.

Comment: Ohhhh I see. I've never seen 'for' loops used like such where both the variables increment or decrement at the same time. I'm a little new to programming :)      Thank you for the help!

Comment: WAIT! Do you think you could explain to me real fast why I need "return true" under the recursive call in my recursive function? This part:for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        if (checkNotBlocked(col, i)) {
            board[col][i] = true;
            if (NQueens(col + 1))
                return true;

            board[col][i] = false;
        }
    }                                         I don't understand what purpose it serves. My tutor told me to put it there but didn't do a good job explaining it well.

Comment: Glad to be of help.  As I said, check the syntax; I don't recall for sure whether Java allows multiple-statement loop controls as **C** does.  If not, you'll have to hand-maintain the value of **j** outside the **for** command (initialize before the loop, decrement at the end of the loop, but test with **i** in the **for** controls).

Comment: The recursive call reads something like this:  "Given the queens I've already placed, return **True** if I can also place the remaining queens (starting with the next column).  If not, then wipe the most recent queen off the board ... and let the **for** loop try the next row for this queen."